# Transferring files from usb to internal memory?

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, usb-drive

I am making a android app when I plug a flash drive into my tablet or phone via OTG usb, it will transfer the files off of it to a specified location. Now, it will transfer if I specify a file name, but how can I get it to transfer all the files without having to specify a name? I am using fileinput/fileoutput with byte array.

```
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
```

public class filetransfer extends Activity {

```
Button btnsend;
String extstorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityfiletransfer);
    btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
    try
    {
        runtime.exec("su -c");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }



    btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence scs = "Folder Doesn't Exist, Creating now, Checking for Flash Drive....";
        CharSequence mvng = "Folder already exist, checking now for flash drive....";
        CharSequence chk1 = "Flash Drive detected, transferring files now.";
        CharSequence chk2 = "Flash Drive Is Not Detected";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast bldng = Toast.makeText(context, scs, duration);
        Toast mvfldr = Toast.makeText(context, mvng, duration);
        Toast chkffd = Toast.makeText(context, chk1, duration);
        Toast chkffd2 = Toast.makeText(context, chk2, duration);

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            File src = new File(extstorage + "/FILEBACKUP");
            File usbdrive = new File(extstorage + "/usbStorage/sda1");
            if(!src.exists())
            {
                src.mkdirs();
                bldng.show();
                if(!usbdrive.exists())
                {
                    chkffd2.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    chkffd.show();
                    copyfiles();
                }

            }

            else
            {

                mvfldr.show();
                if(!usbdrive.exists())
                {
                    chkffd2.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    chkffd.show();
                    copyfiles();
                }

            }
    }
        private void copyfiles()
        {
            String pathofd = "/sdcard/usbStorage/sda1";
            String internalpath = "/sdcard/FILEBACKUP";

            File dir = new File(pathofd);
            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File afile : files)
            {
                if(afile.isFile())
                {
                    copyFile(afile.getAbsolutePath(), internalpath, afile.getName());
                }
            }


            try
            {


            }

                /*OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/FILEBACKUP");
                InputStream myinput = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/usbStorage/");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while((length=myinput.read(buffer))>0)
                {
                    myoutput.write(buffer);
                }
                myoutput.flush();

                myoutput.close();

                myinput.close();

            }*/
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        private void copyFile(String absolutePath, String internalpath,
                String name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try
            {
                OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(extstorage + "/FILEBACKUP/");
                InputStream myinput = new FileInputStream(extstorage + "/usbStorage/sda1");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while((length=myinput.read(buffer))>0)
                {
                    myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                myoutput.flush();

                myoutput.close();

                myinput.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        }




        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activityfiletransfer,
                menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just list the files in the directory:

```
String pathOfFlashDrive = <path of flash drive goes here>;
String internalPath = <internal destination path goes here>;

File dir = new File( pathOfFlashDrive );
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for( File aFile : files ) {
    if( aFile.isFile()  ) {
        copyFile( aFile.getAbsolutePath(), internalPath + aFile.getName() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems interesting but if it lists my files instead of copying them, then this defeats my goal? I see it copies the files but IDK where I am suppose to put the destination directory. :/

Comment: Your question stated that you know how to copy one file. My code helps you copy the entire directory. You'll have to "list" them to know which files to copy. You will need to supply the paths. I will update my answer if that, inexplicably, isn't clear from the code.

Comment: Ok, I have one small problem, copyFile gives me red swiggles underneath it, my options were to make a method for it, and I am wondering why? If I have to what do I need to put in the method stub for this to work?

Comment: You said you had the copying worked out, so `copyFile` is where you plug in your code -- ideally as a method, of course. If I had added the stream-copy code in there, it would just have muddled up the example and reduced the usefulness of the answer for future readers.

Comment: Ok, I decided to include the code so you have better understanding. I am sure I did something wrong. Hopefully you can find out what I messed up on.

Comment: Well, what's the problem? I don't have time to build a project, set up a test environment and debug your code for you.

Comment: Well, no, Im not asking for that. I think it may help if you saw the code. More importantly if I set up the code you gave me correctly.

Comment: You said "I am sure I did something wrong." -- What is the problem you see that makes you say that? Does your code not work? Does it not compile?

Comment: When I set the inputstream to specific file name it works. When I just have the directory it won't transfer the files inside the sda1 folder. I was also wanting to put it in a .tar when it transferred over to the back up location.

Comment: Change `File src = new File(extstorage + "/FILEBACKUP");` to `File src = new File(extstorage + "FILEBACKUP");`

Comment: And change `File usbdrive = new File(extstorage + "/usbStorage/sda1");` to `File usbdrive = new File(extstorage + "usbStorage/sda1");`

Comment: naa that didn't help, kept throwing flash drive not detected and kept saying the folder doesnt exist, which clearly it did since it had already been made.